# Formula combination of SUMIFS, Tables & Variables in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to loop through the Headers of the Table and then populate the formula as mentioned below:

```
        Dim headerRng As Range
        
        For Each headerRng In IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName2).Range.Rows(1).Cells
            Debug.Print headerRng
            If headerRng.Value <> "Function" And headerRng.Value <> "Team Members" And headerRng.Value <> "Accuracy %" Then
                IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName2).ListColumns(headerRng.Value).DataBodyRange.Select
                Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & TableName & Chr(34) & " & ""["" & [@[Team Members]] & CHAR(10) & ""Volumes"" & ""]"")," & Chr(34) & TableName & Chr(34) & " & ""["" & [@[Sub-Function]] & ""]"",LEFT(" & Chr(34) & headerRng.Value & Chr(34) & ",FIND(""_""," & Chr(34) & headerRng.Value & Chr(34) & ")-1))" 'I'm facing error (application object error)
            End If
        Next
```

Actual formula in Excel sheet looks like:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("IM_012022" & "[" & [@[Team Members]] & CHAR(10) & "Volumes" & "]"),IM_012022[Sub-Function],LEFT(Consolidated_012022[[#Headers],[Corporate Treasury_Volumes]],FIND("_",Consolidated_012022[[#Headers],[Corporate Treasury_Volumes]])-1))
```

I'm trying to replicate the same formula for each header using the loops concept, but somwhere in that formula, I'm missing.

Comment: Instead of `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(" ....`, use `Debug.Print "=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("....` and carefully inspect the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: I would break the string down into sub-strings to check which part is erroring. Most of this is going to be trial and error and using `Debug.Print` as BigBen commented to ensure the string is what you expect.

Comment: yes, I have tried that way, it was taking a bit of time, but finally, I have identified, thank you. I'll post that answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim HeaderRng As Range
        
        For Each HeaderRng In IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName2).Range.Rows(1).Cells
            Debug.Print HeaderRng
            If HeaderRng.Value <> "Function" And HeaderRng.Value <> "Team Members" And HeaderRng.Value <> "Volumes" And Not (HeaderRng.Value Like "*Errors") And HeaderRng.Value <> "Accuracy %" Then
                IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName2).ListColumns(HeaderRng.Value).DataBodyRange.Select
                Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & TableName & Chr(34) & " & ""["" & [@[Team Members]] & CHAR(10) & ""Volumes"" & ""]""),INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & TableName & Chr(34) & " & ""[Sub-Function]""),LEFT(" & Chr(34) & HeaderRng.Value & Chr(34) & "," & InStr(1, HeaderRng.Value, "_") - 1 & "))"
            End If
        Next
```